# Understanding the definition of normal field extension

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field, normal-extension

> We let $E/F$ be an algebraic extension of a field $F$, and define $S$ to be the set of all $F$-conjugates of the elements of $E$. Now we define $F(S)$ the be the field generated by $S$ over $F$.
> rove:
>
> $1$.$F(S)/F$ is a normal extension.
>
> $2$.$E\subseteq F(S)$.

Now for some reason I cant wrap my head around the definition of normal extensions. I tried solving the second item as follows:

$2$. Let $\alpha\in E$. I want to prove that $\alpha\in F(S)$. $\alpha\in E$ and therefore $\alpha$ is algebraic over $F$, meaning there exists a minimal irreduciable polynomial $f(x)$ over $F$ s.t $\alpha$ is its root. Since $\alpha$ is a $F$-conjugation of itself. by definition of $S$ its clear that $\alpha\in F(S)$.

Is my proof correct?

Furthermore, how do I approach the first item? I feel like it's not hard but I'm missing something.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your proof for the second item seems correct. Regarding the first one, do you already know that an algebraic extension $F(S)/F$ is normal iff for all $\alpha \in S$, the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $F$ has all its roots in $F(S)$?

Comment: Yes Im aware of that

Comment: There are multiple ways to define "normal extension". Perhaps you could share which definition it is that you are trying to use?